# Does every number divide some $n^2+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

For every $m \in \mathbb{N}$, does there exist some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m$ divides $n^2+1$?

This question came up as a small side question as part of some research I'm doing. I don't know a lot about number theory, and this looks like one of those questions that could either be really simple or totally beyond the limits of our current knowledge.

Comment: My quadratic residue exposure has cobwebs.  It seems to me that the real question is for which (prime or composite) $m \in \mathbb{N}$, is $(-1)$ a quadratic residue of $(m)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

$4$ cannot divide such an $n^2+1$, because modulo $4$, you have $n^2+1=1$ or $2$.

Comment: Perfect! (I'll accept the question once possible.)

Comment: Wouldn’t $3$ work too?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, actually one can prove that every prime number $p$ such that $p\equiv3 \, [4]$ works.

Answer (score 3):

If $m$ divides $n^2+1$, then $n$ is a unit mod $m$ of order $4$. No prime of the form $4k+3$ can divide $n^2+1$ because in this case the group of units mod $p$ has order $4k+2$, which is not a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Then $n^2\equiv -1 \bmod p$ is possible only if $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

This occurs precisely when $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ ie for $p=5, 13$ but not $p=3, 7, 11$

Now suppose $p$ is a factor of $m$ and that you want to find $n$ with $n^2+1=km$. Modulo $p$, this becomes $n^2\equiv -1$, so any odd prime factor of $m$ must be of the form $p=4r+1$.

There is more to do to specify precisely which $m$ are possible, but this is a start on the general problem.

Comment: See my comment following the OP's query.  In modern Number Theory, has the question been completely solved?  If you have a response that is somewhat lengthy for a comment, perhaps you could edit your answer in response.

Comment: @user2661923 I can't find an exact reference, but I believe that $2$ is allowed as a factor of $m$ and any number of odd primes congruent to $1$ mod $4$ (including prime powers), and this gives a necessary and sufficient condition. The steps are to show that it works for $m$ a prime power, and then to stitch the primes together (Chinese Remainder Theorem). Generalisations of the Legendre Symbol tend to give conditions which are necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: So if (for example) $3|m$, then $(-1)$ is not a quadratic residue of $m$.  Also, if (separately) $4|m$, then $(-1)$ is not a quadratic residue of $m$.  Have I interpreted you correctly?

Comment: @user2661923 Yes. To go further Hardy and Wright have a chapter on congruences to composite moduli, or Hensel's lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel's_lemma), which is what H&W use (essentially adapting Newton's method of approximating zeros of a polynomial to the prime case). Hensel's lemma lifts a solution from $\bmod p^n$ to $\bmod p^{n+1}$ - there are two cases which can arise, and in the second, lifting can fail. I think it is possible to show that there are no failures in this case, but I haven't checked this. This lifting to higher powers is one motivation of the p-adic numbers.